# Spanning discs in contractible 2-d complexes

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

I'm pretty sure this has an easy solution, but I can't seem to find it.

Let $X$ be a contractible $2$-dimensional CW-complex, let $\gamma$ be an embedded loop in $X$, and let $f : D^2 \rightarrow X$ be an embedding of a disc in $X$ which maps the boundary of $D$ to $\gamma$.

My question is the following.  Let $f' : D^2 \rightarrow X$ be a continuous map of a disc into $X$ which takes the boundary of $D$ to $\gamma$.  Must we then have $f(D^2) \subset f'(D^2)$ ?  I'm pretty sure that the answer is yes, but I can't seem to prove it.

Of course, this has an obvious generalization to higher dimensional complexes, and I'd be interested in that too.

Comment: I guess at least you mean $f'$ is also injective

Comment: @Yi Liu: There is no need to assume $f'$ is injective.

Comment: @Tom: Oh you're right. I thought the inclusion is the other way around. never mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I can think of is to take a point $x\in f(D)\setminus f'(D)$, assuming on the contrary. One may assume $x$ lies in the interior of $f(D)$ and the interior of some 2-cell. Then you can remove a small disk $U$ in $f(D)$ which still lies in the 2-cell, and a Mayer–Vietoris sequence argument shows $\gamma$ is homologically nontrivial in $H_1(X\setminus U)$, as $[\gamma]=[\partial U]$. This gives a contradiction.